# Determining when it is the most appropriate time to delete a cached object from core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an iOS app written in Swift that requests data from a server, the server responds with the requested data in JSON format and the app serializes that data into a Core Data object to cache it.

The point of this being that the client doesn't have to keep re-requesting the data from the server. It's worth noting that this data could be around 300 KB - 1 MB because it has the potential to contain alot of text and an image.

The data can easily be re-requested from the server if needed. So my question is how would I determine when it is an appropriate time to delete the object from Core Data so that the app doesn't keep storing more and more until the whole device HDD is full (or just generally using lots of HDD space)? What is the general strategy in a situation like this?

EDIT - For more context on how the app works. Users can search for data which is displayed in a UICollectionView. The server responds to the search query with an array of IDs of the relevant database objects and then the client will request them individually when the UICollectionView needs to display the data. When the client makes a request it first checks if its in memory, if not then checks core data and finally requests the data from the server if its not in core data. If it is pulled from core data then the client will tell the server the objects id and the version it has and the server will respond by either saying it's up-to-date or with the relevant updated information. I expect that most objects will never be updated but there is always a possibility

Comment: This is your app - no one here knows how it works or how often / in what manner the users use the app. We don't know how often the cached data needs updating or even if you are checking for stale cache data. If you are worried about consuming too much space then implement an option for the users to choose the cache size and then delete the oldest / least used data as appropriate to remain within the user chosen value.

Comment: @RoboticCat Yes that is true and I was partially deliberately vague because I wondered what the kind of professional app companies do, would they set a limit on their cache size and delete the oldest / least used data to stay within that value? Or maybe they have a more versatile approach? I've added more context to my situation in the OP